# Moving two div elements in parallel

Tags: jquery

1. When `div1` is clicked `div2` should open.
2. Both `div1` and `div2` should move at the same time.
3. On the click of `div1`, and `div1` should go to its old position.

How to achieve this?

[image]

when i click the above div,both div should open like this.

[image]

This is my code on div1 onclick

```
$("#div2").toggle(function(){
        if($("#div2").is(":visible")){ frmWidth = "240"; }
        if($("#div2").is(":hidden")){ frmWidth = "-60"; }

        $("#div1").css("right",frmWidth+"px");
    });
```

Comment: please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: I think you mean parallel instead of 'parralell'.

Comment: can you further explain with the code you tried

Answer (score 1):

- Wrap both your elements inside a parent `DIV`
- Animate the parent

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div1"></div>
```

css:

```
body {overflow:hidden;}
.div2 {
    background: #ccc;
    width:100px;
    height: 500px;
    float: right;
    margin-right:-100px;


}
.div1 {
    background: #eee;
    width:100px;
    height: 500px;
    float: right;

}
```

js:

```
$true = 1;
$('.div1').click(
    function() {
        if ($true == 0) {
            $('.div2').animate({'margin-right':-100 });
            $true = 1;
        } else {
        $('.div2').animate({'margin-right':0 });
         $true = 0;
        }


});
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/LL9gy2dc/